# Part number / manufacturer of microSD connector of Raspberry PI zero

Tags: raspberry-pi, sd

Do somebody know what is the part number / manufacturer of microSD card of Raspberry PI zero?
I would like to include it on my Digikey cart if possible.
Schematics does not show the part number...

Regards.

[image]

Comment: Are you replacing an existing one? Why do you want that exact part?

Comment: Hi. Is not a replacement. Actually I found it interesting for use on my current PCB layout that is under development.

Comment: I want to check if it is available on Digikey, to buy some samples.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/1040310811/WM6357CT-ND/2804769

Comment: @brhans Thanks very much.